# Python exception for HTTP response codes

Tags: python, http, exception

I'd like to raise a Python-standard exception when an HTTP response code from querying an API is not 200, but what specific exception should I use? For now I raise an OSError:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
  raise OSError("Response " + str(response.status_code)
                  + ": " + response.content)
```

I'm aware of the [documentation for built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html).

Comment: Really depends on what the error is.  If it's caused by bad input (like an unauthorized API key) then `ValueError` would be appropriate.   I can't think off the top of another built-in exception that would apply (aside form Exception :p) so you'd probably want to craft your own exceptions in that case as the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in Python exceptions are probably not a good fit for what you are doing. You will want to subclass the base class `Exception`, and throw your own custom exceptions based on each scenario you want to communicate.

A good example is [how the Python Requests HTTP library defines its own exceptions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions):

> In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused
>   connection, etc), Requests will raise a `ConnectionError` exception.
>
> In the rare event of an invalid HTTP response, Requests will raise an
>   `HTTPError` exception.
>
> If a request times out, a `Timeout` exception is raised.
>
> If a request exceeds the configured number of maximum redirections, a
>   `TooManyRedirects` exception is raised.
>
> All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises inherit from
>   `requests.exceptions.RequestException`.

Comment: If you are in fact using the Requests library, this is probably what you want: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status

Comment: Those links throw 404s..... :D

Comment: Try this: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status

Answer (score 36):

You can simply call [`Response.raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) on your response:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/doesnt-exist'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>>
>>> print r.status_code
404
>>> r.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "requests/models.py", line 831, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found
```

This will raise a [`requests.HTTPError`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py#L30-L31) for any `4xx` or `5xx` response.

See the docs on [Response Status Code](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) for a more complete example.

---

Note that this does *not* exactly do what you asked (`status != 200`): It will not raise an exception for `201 Created` or `204 No Content`, or any of the `3xx` redirects - but this is most likely the behavior you want: `requests` will just follow the redirects, and the other `2xx` are usually just fine if you're dealing with an API.